# play framework routes trouble (400 bad request)

Tags: json, jquery, post, playframework-2.0

I'm having trouble making a POST to the play framework - this may not even be Play related as much as HTTP related.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'http://localhost:9000/start',
    data: {
        myJson:JSON.stringify(arg)
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

where `arg` is an array of strings, ie:
   `['a', 'b', 'c']`

The route I'm trying to use to capture this is:

```
POST    /start      controllers.Application.startIt(myJson)
```

What am I doing wrong?  As of right now (if the route is capturing correctly), that function will never return a 400.  There is no output to the Play console, only javascript:

`POST http://localhost:9000/start 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: Please show your `Application.startIt` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation explains when a BadRequest error code is returned](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal) by the framework. The problem comes from your router file. You define a route */start* which will trigger a method call *startIt*, but the method has an argument and the framework does not know which value it should pass.

To handle correctly JSON requests, have a look to the [dedicated part of the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaJsonRequests).