# Play Framework JQuery AJAX REST Post call returns Bad Request error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, playframework

I am building an autosave feature for my Play app and when my JQuery runs, it returns a Bad Request error (Error 400).

EDIT: I updated my code by removing the parameter I was passing to the controller and followed the documentation here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaJsonActions

Here is what is returned in the Chrome console:

```
addptp:326 POST http://localhost:9000/autosave 400 (Bad Request)
send    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   addptp:326
each    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
each    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
autosave    @   addptp:325
(anonymous) @   addptp:188
```

My JQuery:

```
var timer;
var restURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port == "" ? "" : (":" + window.location.port));

$(document).ready(function() {
    // JSON REST Autosave...
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        autosave();
    }, 6000);
});

function autosave() {
    alert("Autosave");
    $('form').each(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: restURL + "/autosave",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Success!");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the route in the `routes` file:

```
POST   /autosave   controllers.Application.restAutosaveAdultPTP()
```

Here is my Java function in my controller:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result restAutosaveAdultPTP() {
    // Let's get the current request in JSON and parse...
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if (json == null) {
        return badRequest("Expecting Json data");
    } else {
        return ok("json: " + json);
    }
}
```

Based on the forum posts I have read, I have all the needed parameters for the AJAX call.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [play framework routes trouble (400 bad request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127008/play-framework-routes-trouble-400-bad-request)

Comment: I followed these instructions - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaJsonActions - and removed the parameter so I am passing no values in the URL.  I continue to get the error.  I have updated my original post with the changes.