# Building Autosave function in Play Framework using JQuery and Java but running into 400 Bad Request or 404 Not Found error

Tags: java, jquery, json, playframework, url-encoding

I am building an autosave feature in my Play app using JQuery in the model and processing the request in the controller.

I originally posted (Post 1) this:

[Play Framework JQuery AJAX REST Post call returns Bad Request error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174663/play-framework-jquery-ajax-rest-post-call-returns-bad-request-error)

but that was marked as a possible duplicate of this (Post 2):

[play framework routes trouble (400 bad request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127008/play-framework-routes-trouble-400-bad-request)

I received no answers on my original post (Post 1), so I was instructed to repost my question.

I followed Post 2 and removed the parameter I was passing since it was a possible issue with my request, based on Post 2.  The documentation referenced in Post 2 was in Scala (and for an older version of Play - I am using 2.5) and my app in is in Java, so it did not really help me.  I found this in the Play documentation:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJsonActions

I read and followed that document and updated my code.

However, I still am receiving the Bad Request (400) or Not Found (404) error.  I don't receive any detailed messages, so I am not sure where I am making a mistake.

Here is what is returned in the Chrome console:

```
addptp:414 POST http://localhost:9000/autosave 404 (Not Found)
send    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   addptp:414
each    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
each    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
autosave    @   addptp:413
(anonymous) @   addptp:185
```

Here is the JQuery in the view:

```
var timer;
var restURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port == "" ? "" : (":" + window.location.port));

$(document).ready(function() {
    // JSON REST Autosave...
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        autosave();
    }, 6000);
});

    function autosave() {
        alert("Autosave");
        $('form').each(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: restURL + "/autosave",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Success!");
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert("Error!");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Here is my controller code in Java:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded.class)
public Result restAutosaveAdultPTP() {
    // Let's get the current request in JSON and parse...
    Map<String, String[]> json = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
    if (json == null) {
        return badRequest("Expecting Json data");
    } else {
        return ok("json: " + json);
    }
}
```

Here is my `routes` file entry:

```
POST   /autosave   controllers.Application.restAutosaveAdultPTP()
```

Here is the request and response info...

General:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/autosave
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:9000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 26917
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 25 Jan 2018 18:34:15 GMT
```

Request Headers:

```
POST /autosave HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2739
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:9000
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:9000/addptp
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=a37c3087c9d5d3f4129057c964ca9a90eef80fe5-SESSION_ID=kfs7q8vohk3ammlfcnfka0j1p9&email=dzeller44%40gmail.com&userTimeout=1516880046558
```

Payload

```
legacy_Provider_Id=&new_Provider_Id=&provider_Name=&alternate_Name_DBA=&setting_Type=&waivers_Served=&total_Number_Served=&total_Number_on_Waivers=&street_Address=&apartment=&city=&state=&zip=&phone=&email1=&email2=&contact_Person=&updates=&main_PTP_Address=&duplicate_docs=&other_Rights_NonCompliance_Description=&other_Remedy_for_Rights_Description=&details_for_Rights_Action_Plan=&remedy_Rights_Incurred_Cost_Description=&remedy_Rights_One_Time_Costs=&remedy_Rights_Recurring_Annual_Costs=&person_for_Rights_Action_Plan=&status_Rights_Action_Plan=---+Select+Status+---&other_Choice_NonCompliance_Description=&other_Remedy_for_Choice_Description=&detail_for_Choice_Action_Plan=&remedy_Choice_Incurred_Cost_Description=&remedy_Choice_One_Time_Costs=&remedy_Choice_Recurring_Annual_Costs=&person_for_Choice_Action_Plan=&status_of_Choice_Action_Plan=---+Select+Status+---&other_Integration_NonCompliance_Description=&other_Remedy_for_Integration_Description=&detail_for_Integration_Action_Plan=&remedy_Integration_Incurred_Cost_Description=&remedy_Integration_One_Time_Costs=&remedy_Integration_Recurring_Annual_Costs=&person_for_Integration_Action_Plan=&status_for_Integration_Action_Plan=---+Select+Status+---&other_Remedy_for_Institutional_Factors_Description=&detail_for_Institutional_Action_Plan=&remedy_Institutional_Incurred_Cost_Description=&remedy_Institutional_One_Time_Costs=&remedy_Institutional_Recurring_Annual_Costs=&person_for_Institutional_Action_Plan=&status_of_Institutional_Action_Plan=---+Select+Status+---&ptp_Edited_Date=&ptp_Status_Notes=&update_Due=&compliance_Status=---+Select+Status+---&ensures_Rights=---+Select+Status+---&optimizes_Autonomy=---+Select+Status+---&selected_by_Person=---+Select+Status+---&options_in_PC_Plan=---+Select+Status+---&facilitates_Choice=---+Select+Status+---&integrated_in_Community=---+Select+Status+---&enforceable_Lease=---+Select+Status+---&eviction_Protections=---+Select+Status+---&bedroom_Privacy=---+Select+Status+---&bedroom_Locks=---+Select+Status+---&choice_of_Roommates=---+Select+Status+---&freedom_to_Decorate=---+Select+Status+---&free_Schedule_Access_to_Food=---+Select+Status+---&visitors_any_Time=---+Select+Status+---&physically_Accessible=---+Select+Status+---&modifications_PC_Plan=---+Select+Status+---&setting_NonInstitutional=---+Select+Status+---&heightened_Scrutiny_Description=&cdphe_Lead=&site_Visit_Status=---+Select+Status+---&site_Visit_Date=&site_Visit_Team=&documents_Detail=&findings_from_Documents=&summary_of_Findings=&promising_Practices=&additional_Notes=&follow_up_Visit_Status=---+Select+Status+---&additional_Notes_2=&follow_up_Date=&follow_up_Team=&documents_Detail_2=&findings_from_Documents_2=&summary_of_Findings_2=&promising_Practices_2=
```

As noted in the comments below, why is it looking for json and not a form-url-encoded in the Request Headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

I appreciate any direction or help you can provide.

Comment: Can you please provide the full request and response (headers + body) that you're sending and receiving? My hunch is that `$(this).serialize()` is not producing valid JSON, but I need to see the request body to confirm this and I'd like to be able to see the response body to know if the line `badRequest("Expecting Json data")` is being reached.

Comment: @RichDougherty - I updated my post to include the Request and Response header and body info.  Let me know if there is anything else you would need.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$(this).serialize()` is encoding the data in URL-encoded notation but the `@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)` annotation and the `request().body().asJson()` code in your controller show that you're expecting JSON encoding.

Docs for `serialize`: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

> The `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

Instead of using JSON's `serialize` method you probably want to use something like JavaScript's `stringify`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string

Alternatively you can change your Play code to expect a URL-encoded value. See the docs about `FormUrlEncoded` here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaBodyParsers

> [`FormUrlEncoded`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/play/mvc/BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded.html): Parses the body as a form.

If you change the Play behaviour, remember to also change the `contentType` you send so it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`.

Comment: I changed the `serialize()` to this `data: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray())` and now am receiving a `400 Not Found` error.  Do you have an example of how to stringify the form?

Comment: I also tried to change the BodyParser, but getting the same error - 400 Not Found.  I changed to `@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded.class)` and set the JQuery back to `data: $(this).serialize()` and changed the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  I am guessing I missed something...

Comment: Can you please show the new request/response headers and body?

Comment: FYI if you change to use a URL-encoded body you can't use `request().body().asJson()`.

Comment: I changed my controller function to `Map<String, String[]> json = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();` but still getting the 400 Not Found error.  New headers and body are posted in my main post above.

Comment: At a glance I can see that the request `Content-Type` doesn't match the the request body - it needs to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`. Play will certainly be confused by this.

Comment: @ Rich Dougherty I updated my post above to reflect the current state of the code and headers/body.  I am sending a form-url-encoded and looking for a form-url-encoded.  However as the post says, why does it accept json only?

Comment: Play will ignore the `Accept` header unless you change your action to take it into account so don't worry about the fact that your request says it will accept JSON. I'm mostly worried about the 404 response which suggests that basic routing isn't working. Can you put a println into your action to verify that it actually gets called?

Comment: I changed my controller function to `@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded.class)
 public Result restAutosaveAdultPTP() {
  System.out.println("In REST service...");
  // Let's get the current request in JSON and parse...
  Map<String, String[]> json = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
  if (json == null) {
   return badRequest("Expecting Json data");
  } else {
   return ok("json: " + json);
  }
 }` but it never made it to that `System.out.println` line...

Comment: You have a problem with your routing then. You'll need to play around with the `routes` file and the method (`POST`) and URL (`/autosave`) you use until the 404 error goes away and you successfully get a println working.

Comment: Fixed up the route in the `routes` file - had the route named incorrectly - doh!  Works great now!

Comment: Got there in the end!

Comment: Thanks for the help Rich!  You've been a great help, so I am hoping you could help with one more question.  In the `return.ok()` in my controller, what do I need to send back?  I have tried a `String` variable, but that fails.  I have tried to format JSON and send that back, but not sure how to process or handle.  Any ideas or samples?  If I need to create a new post, please let me know.  Code --- `String returnString = "{\"ptpkey\": \""+ newPTPKey + "\"}";return ok(returnString)`

Comment: Please create a new question - you can link from a comment if you want.